# how to query to return distinct or unique - breeze.js angular.js

Tags: angularjs, odata, breeze

I am accessing corporate enterprise service bus endpoint to get data. I have a angular.js app (1.5 version) and using breeze with it to load data from this service. I want to know how I can get a list of unique values on one property. Can someone tell me? Thanks. Below is my code to access data. If i do a .distinct() after select below, that throws error.

```
getProductBaseInformation(): ng.IPromise<any[]> {
        var query = this.breeze.EntityQuery.from("ProductBaseInformation").select("ProductCode");
        return this.manager.executeQuery(query);
    }
```

Comment: Do note, I don't want to add a distinct method on server side...I want to do it all on client side only...if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it cannot be done! :-(

Comment: I believe it can't be done because OData doesn't support 'Distinct' right now.